# X server intermittent 'connection refused'

Tags: linux, xserver

I have Linux on Raspi I have set up a while ago, and have been using it via ssh with X server. Lately, it became clear that Raspi cannot handle the apps I am developing and I've switched to WSL on a secondary laptop.

**Current use case:**
Using Putty and X-serv on my main machine (WIN7), SSH into another laptop (WIN10) on the same network with Linux installed on WSL.

I use two IDEs (Anjuta and Codeblocks) to develop a GUI app.

I've added yesterday a new non-root user to WSL, tried to make X-serv work for the new user and messed around with xauth and ./Xauthority file. Gave up in frustration and successfully managed to run my IDEs and app as the root user.

Today, root again, the following happened:

- First try:

  1. start Anjuta: runs in X-window
  2. start Codeblocks: "Putty X11 proxy: Authorisation not recognised" error
  3. close all windows
- Second try:

  1. start Anjuta: runs ok
  2. run code in Anjuta: "Putty X11 proxy: Authorisation not recognised" error
  3. close all
- Third try:

  1. start Anjuta: runs ok
  2. run code in Anjuta: the app is executed in a new X-window
  3. start Codeblocks: "Putty X11 proxy: Authorisation not recognised" error
  4. close all
- Forth try:

  1. start Anjuta: runs ok
  2. start Codeblocks: runs ok
  3. run code in Anjuta: "Putty X11 proxy: Authorisation not recognised" error

**Question:**
Why is X-server intermittently refusing the connection and how can I fix it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the routine that solves the problem:

1. In the first opened terminal, run **`xauth list`** and copy the output

> localhost/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  e17b************************7c8a

2. In any new opened terminal, run xauth add with the cookie as argument: **`xauth add localhost/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  e17b************************7c8a`**

Comment: You could also try `ssh`ing in with the `-X` option that forwards your X connections.